# what is the control flow of django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, tastypie, control-flow

I am developing an api for a webapp. I was initially using tastypie and switched to `django-rest-framework (drf)`. Drf seems very easy to me. What I intend to do is to create nested user profile object. My models are as below

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class nestedmodel(models.Model):
    info = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    add_info = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    nst = models.ForeignKey(nestedmodel)
```

I have other models that have Foreignkey Relation. My Serializers are as below

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import serializers
from quickstart.models import UserProfile, nestedmodel


class NestedSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = nestedmodel
        fields = ('info', )

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'groups')


class GroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('url', 'name')

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    nst = NestedSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        user = UserSerializer(many=True)
        nested = NestedSerializer(many=True)
        fields = ('nst', 'user')
```

I can override methods like `create(self, validated_data):` without any issues. But What I want to know is `to which method should the response returned by create() goes`, or in other words `Which method calls create()`. In tastypie `Resources.py` is the file to override to implement custom methods. And Resources.py contains the order in which methods are being called. Which is the file in drf that serves the same purpose and illustrates the control flow like Resources.py in tastypie?.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but isn't the result of `create` a `Response` object which contains the newly created object and is usually returned to the viewer?

Comment: oh..yes. I will edit question.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

So the flow goes something like:

1. Viewset's [`create()`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L18-L23) method which is implemented in `CreateModelMixin`
2. That creates serializer and validates it. Once valid, it uses viewset's [`perform_create()`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L25-L26)
3. That calls serializer's [`save()`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L138-L180) method
4. That then in turn calls serializer's either [`create()`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L175) or [`update()`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L170) depending if instance was passed to serializer (which it was not in step 1)
5. `create()` or `update()` then create/update instance which is then saved on `serializer.instance`
6. Viewset then returns response with data coming from [`serializer.data`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L23)
7. [`serializer.data`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L210-L228) is actually a property on serializer which is responsible for serializing the instance to a dict
8. To serialize data, [`to_representation()`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L438-L458) is used.
9. Then response data (Python dict) is rendered to a output format via [renderers](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/renderers.py) which could be json, xml, etc

> And Resources.py contains the order in which methods are being called. Which is the file in drf that serves the same purpose and illustrates the control flow like Resources.py in tastypie?.

Guess that would be a combination of files. Its probably better to think in terms of classes/concepts you are touching since in DRF you can inherit from multiple things for create your classes. So the thing which glues everything together are [viewsets](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/). Then there are various viewset mixins which actually glue the viewset to the serializer and different CRUD operations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After save(), what method is called to return json response? Or is it written in save() itself?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Control flow greatly depend on the class that is being inherited. Anyway I could not find out a way to get an object if it exists else create a new one. I tried overriding `save()` and `create()` methods of `HyperLinkedModelSerializer` as well as `Modelserializer`. Anyway, control is not passed to both methods. I think `this field must be unique` if an object exists and that object serves as a non-nullable field, is generated at validation stage. But its still unclear how is it made at validation since django generates that error at the time of object creation.

Comment: `update_or_create`  is not really applicable to RESTful APIs. User either creates object via `POST` on `*-list` URL (e.g. `/api/resource/`) or uses `PUT` to update object on `*-detail` URL (e.g. `/api/resource/<pk>/`). Combining the two is not a very good idea. If you absolutely need that, then you should create a custom route for that...

Comment: I've found [Classy DRF](http://www.cdrf.co/) an invaluable resource for understanding these lifecycle questions

Comment: Can't believe this isn't included in the DRF doc site, this piece of info is so important and fundamental. Was very confused when I want to start changing something, but ended up bouncing between viewsets & serializer without clue. This answer helped a ton!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out second part of question myself. get/create object can be done by using custom code in overriden `def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):` in `views.py`. Code is as pasted below. Once Again, for clarity this is `views.py` not serializers.py. Also json with posted values can be accessed from `request.DATA`

```
class NestedViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows Nested objects to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = nestedmodel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NestedSerializer
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        info = request.DATA['info']
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.DATA['user']['username'])
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
        nst = nestedmodel.objects.create(info=info, user=user, profile=profile)
        serialized_obj = serializers.serialize('json', [ nst, ])
        json_serialized = json.loads(serialized_obj)
        data = json.dumps(json_serialized[0])
        return Response(data)
```

Thanks for the help @miki275 :)

Comment: fyi. your solutions does not really use any of the DRF tools like a serializer